# Google maps - add clickable Czech republic regions overlays

Tags: google-maps

I'm trying to create a map of Czech republic with it's regions, each region should be a link to specific page.

I know I can use Google Maps polygons for this, however, is there a better way to build this functionality?

Maybe it would be possible to somehow use Region Geocharts for this?

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. There are [event listeners](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/events) that one can apply to a chart.

```
var urls = {"region-name1":"http://url/to/region/1.html", ... }; //using region names as defined in library
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'regionClick', function(e){
  window.location.href = urls[e.region];
});
```

When the region is clicked, it fires the function in the event listener, passing the argument `e` as `{region:'CA'}` or some equivalent to that.

Comment: Thanks, works great! It's was also helpful to find out the region codes!